# How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, query-string

Suppose I have URLs with query string parameters like these:

```
/index.php?book=DesignPatterns&page=139
/index.php?book=Refactoring&page=285
```

Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html), how can I redirect them to SES URLs like these?

```
/DesignPatterns/139
/Refactoring/285
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} book=(\w+)&page=(\d+)  
RewriteRule ^index.php /%1/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Because [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) only looks at the path (up to but not including the question mark), use [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to capture the values in the query string.

Note that the matches from `RewriteCond` are captured in `%1`,
`%2`, etc., rather than `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Also note the `?` at the end of `RewriteRule`. It tells mod_rewrite
not to append the original query string to the new URL, so you end up with
`/DesignPatterns/151` intead of
`/DesignPatterns/151?book=DesignPatterns&page=151`.

The `[L,R=301]` flags do two things:

1. `L` ensures that no other rules that might otherwise match will be processed (in other words, it ensures this is the "last" rule processed).
2. `R=301` causes the server to send back a redirect response.
   Instead of rewriting, it tells the client to try again with the new
   URL. The `=301` makes it a [permanent redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary), so that, among other things, search engines will know to replace the old URL with the new URL in their indexes.

Comment: You probably also want the [L] flag when you have multiple rewrite rules. The [L] flag stops processing after the rule has matched, and the [R] flag DOES NOT implicitly include it.

Comment: The $ vs % were killing me. I had no idea. Thank you!

Comment: To not append the original query string to the new url use `[QSD]` flag (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsd)

Comment: Answers like this make me wish I could star them for later easy finding. Instead I end up starring the question.

Comment: @Luciano just recognize it by upvoting the answer on a question you starred.

Comment: isn't this invalid?

you'd need to escape the dot in `^index.php` with `^index\.php`

Comment: I spend like 4 hours debugging :D until I googled and I discovered that mod rewrite doesn't match the query string