# .htaccess get url to uri segments

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to convert the 
url:

```
http://example.com/calendar/?start=1281052769&end=1283731169
```

into the url:

```
http://example.com/calendar/1281052769/1283731169
```

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} start=(.*)
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING} end=(.*)
RewriteRule   ^calendar$     http://example.com/calendar/%1/%2[R,L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start\=([^&]+)\&end\=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /calendar/%1/%2 [R,L]
```