# Redirect example.com/?p=25 to example.com/25 in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

I'm using CodeIgniter and I want to redirect links like this:

```
example.com/?p=25
```

to this:

```
example.com/25
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14322464/183254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.askaboutphp.com/58/codeigniter-mixing-segment-based-url-with-querystrings.html

or

to create url like this : http://yyyy.com/article/finishing-dan-snapshop-salkulator

add this code in routes.php
$route['article/(:any)'] = "article/readmore/$1";

description :
1. article  : class name
2. readmore : method from class article
3. $1       : get value from uri segment 2 value

Answer (score 0):

its .htaccess rewrite rule.make sure u have activated mod_rewrite .then put this line into website application root .htaccess file

> RewriteRule    ^/([0-9]+)/?$    p=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle product
>   requests