# How to redirect a link with multiple parameters to a simple .html link

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Old link :
 http://example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=17&Itemid=52

New Link :
 http://example.com/newlink.html

Big THANKS !

Comment: Do you mean rewrite or redirect? Direct will change the browser location and load a new file. Rewrite will change the appearance of the url in the address bar to what you want.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

from the url given, I would guess that you are using Joomla!. You may very well turn on Joomla's own SEO capabilities in the backend or have a look at extensions.joomla.org for SEO components.