# Replacing link with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to replace link but ending with internal server error

```
www.domain.com/profile.php?id=1
```

> i want it to ->

```
www.domain.com/1
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^login\.php\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/domain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Line 4 can never work, because you can not match the part after ? with RewriteRule. For this, you can use RewriteCond [like in this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite).

Comment: THANKS i am trying :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /profile.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: ty let me check this on server :)