# How to extract GET parameter argument value in Apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have following URL:

```
myUrl?path=123&param=val
```

Can you help me to write regular expression which will return path value. i.e

> 123

at this case?

P.S.

I have 
`REQUEST_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` arguments.

### P.S.

more global goal:

rewrite following url:

```
site.com/cat1/cat2?path=val&param=ololo
```

to

```
site.com/cat1/cat2/val
```

P.P.S

I have read following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2252242/2674303

but there are a bit another situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*(?:^|&))path=([^&]*)(.*)
RewriteRule ^/?cat1/cat2$ /cat1/cat2/%2? [PT]
```

Note, the final '?' drops the old query string.

Comment: That's weird, it shouldn't even result in a redirect. Where do you expect the port to be retained when only the path and query are changing in the server?

Comment: sorry I don't understand you.