# URL Rewrite with dynamic URL before parameters

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite my URL below

```
https://xxx.xxx/159/prepared-is-me-marianne-pleasure-likewise-debating-wonder?show=199
```

to become like this

```
https://xxx.xxx/159/prepared-is-me-marianne-pleasure-likewise-debating-wonder/show/199
```

My current rewrite is this

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/(.*)?show=(.*)$ /$1/$2/show/$3 [L]
```

But it does not to work.

as I test here my rule http://htaccess.mwl.be/ it says the my rule doesn't meet the condition of the input URL

Comment: You're saying you want A to B but your rule is trying B to A. Also, "seems not to work" doesn't tell me what your problem is. You should write the output you get and what you expect

Comment: @pmmaga I cleared out my rule sorry

Comment: Better! But I still don't know which result you're getting.

Comment: @pmmaga well i test here my rule http://htaccess.mwl.be/ but it seems to say that the condition doesn't meet on the input URL. I thinking i'm incorrect on the regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I match query string variables with mod\_rewrite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php to create my rewriting rules, hope it help !

Answer (score 0):

As explained [on this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite), RewriteRules do not take the querystring into account, only the actual path. So your `?show=` part of your original URL will never be matched.