# HTACCESS multiple parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I have this URL

```
https://www.example.com/detail.php?slug=ashutosh&event=c7da097d2c5a11e9821a01ec0a18050e&eventID=cb20a1fcb9bd8c3d8240d3ccb903c32637e044f10c6a2d09b&utm_source=t&utm_campaign=main&utm_medium=Test
```

i need this type of URL

```
https://www.example.com/user/ashutosh?event=c7da097d2c5a11e9821a01ec0a18050e&eventID=cb20a1fcb9bd8c3d8240d3ccb903c32637e044f10c6a2d09b&utm_source=t&utm_campaign=main&utm_medium=Test
```

pls help any one

Comment: You can capture values from a query string using `RewriteCond`. See [How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: can you generate htaccess code for that?

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify any condition *when* to apply this rule I assume that it is to get always applied when the base URL starts with `/user/` followed by a user name (a word) and nothing else. And that the user name should get specified as `slug``parameter, that at least is what your example suggests...

That would result in a rewriting rule like the following:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?user/(\w+)/?$ /detail.php?slug=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [END,QSA]
```

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).