# Set 410 url with ending parameter htacces

Tags: .htaccess

Im trying to remove list of url marked as duplicate in search console, those url are already 404 but it creates double 301 redirect before ended up as 404

```
https://www.domaincom/2017/11/post.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+library+(library+-+library+info,+student)&m=1
```

Creating 301 redirect to

```
https://www.domaincom/2017/11/post.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20library%20%28library%20-%20library%20info%2C%20student%29&m=1
```

And creating another 301 redirect before ended up as 404, i did create 410 rules for each individual url but its seems doesnt work

```
  Redirect 410 /2017/11/post.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+library+(library+-+library+info,+student)&m=1
  Redirect 410 /2017/11/post.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20library%20%28library%20-%20library%20info%2C%20student%29&m=1
```

But both url still having 301 status before final status 404 not 410 ( maybe because url get encoded?), Im trying to set 410 every url having ending parameter

```
?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium
```

Can Someone help me with correct htacces code?

====edit====

this one works incase someone need it

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} utm_source=feedburner
 RewriteRule .* - [G,L]
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The `Redirect` directive matches path prefixes, you can not use it to match the query string part of a URL; for that you will need to use mod_rewrite, a `RewriteCond` can perform checks on that using the respective variable.

Comment: hi 04FS can you be more specific about that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite