# URL rewrite with HTACCESS for multiple language support

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking to add multiple language support to my website. Is it possible to use the `.htaccess` file to change something like:

- `example.com/dir/?lang=en` to `example.com/en/dir/`
- `example.com/main/?lang=de` to `example.com/de/main/`
- `example.com/main/page.php?lang=de` to `example.com/de/main/page.php`

Where this works with any possible directories - so if for instance later on I made a new directory, I wouldn't need to add to this. In the above example, I want the latter to be what the user types in/is in the address bar, and the start to be how it is used internally.

Comment: What have you tried before? Which is your actual .htaccess?

Comment: @AdFortia currently my .htaccess is empty as I am starting again to completely overhaul. I am not sure how to even begin this - so I have tried nothing yet.

Comment: The only "correct" answer to the question is probably "yes" ... which isn't very helpful, I'll admit, but since we don't *really* know what you're doing, it's not possible to give a more specific answer. Normally you'd punt all requests to an application _routing_ file and let that sort things out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Capture everything before, `?lang=`, and then everything after that. Move everything after to the start, and append the before after it.

Comment: Also, you might want to have a look at how to specifically [capture the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite).

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Please share your attempts and where you're stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use the `.htaccess` file to change something like:
>
> - `example.com/dir/?lang=en` to `example.com/en/dir/`

Yes, except that you don't change the URL to `example.com/en/dir/` in `.htaccess`. You change the URL to `example.com/en/dir/` in your internal links in your application, before you change anything in `.htaccess`. This is the canonical URL and is "what the user types in/is in the address bar" - as you say.

You then use `.htaccess` to *internally rewrite* the request from `example.com/en/dir/`, back into the URL your application understands, ie. `example.com/dir/?lang=en` (or rather `example.com/dir/index.php?lang=en` - see below). This is entirely hidden from the user. The user only ever sees `example.com/en/dir/` - even when they look at the HTML source.

So, we need to rewrite `/<lang>/<url-path>/` to `/<url-path>/?lang=<lang>`. Where `<lang>` is assumed to be a 2 character lowercase language code. If you are offering only a small selection of languages then this should be explicitly stated to avoid conflicts. We can also handle any additional query string on the original request (if this is requried). eg. `/<lang>/<url-path>/?<query-string>` to `/<url-path>/?lang=<lang>&<query-string>`.

A slight complication here is that a URL of the form `/dir/?lang=en` is not strictly a valid endpoint and requires further rewriting. I expect you are relying on mod_dir to issue an internal subrequest for the DirectoryIndex, eg. `index.php`? So, really, this should be rewritten directly to `/dir/index.php?lang=en` - or whatever the DirectoryIndex document is defined as.

For example, in your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite "/<lang>/<directory>/" to `/<directory>/index.php?lang=<lang>"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2/index.php -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*?)/?$ $2/index.php?lang=$1 [L]

# Rewrite "/<lang>/<directory>/<file>" to `/<directory>/<file>?lang=<lang>"
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$2 -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.+) $2?lang=$1 [L]
```

If you have just two languages (as in your example), or a small subset of known languages then change the `([a-z]{2})` subpattern to use *alternation* and explicitly identify each language code, eg. `(en|de|ab|cd)`.

This does assume you don't have physical directories in the document root that consist of 2 lowercase letters (or match the specific language codes).

Only URLs where the destination directory (that contains `index.php`) or file exists are rewritten.

This will also rewrite requests for the document root (not explicitly stated in your examples). eg. `example.com/en/` (trailing slash required here) is rewritten to `/index.php?lang=en`.

The regex could be made slightly more efficient if requests for directories *always* contain a trailing slash. In the above I've assumed the trailing slash is optional, although this does potentially create a duplicate content issue unless you resolve this in some other way (eg. `rel="canonical"` link element). So, in the code above, both `example.com/en/dir/` (trailing slash) and `example.com/en/dir` (no trailing slash) are both accessible and both return the same resource, ie. `/dir/index.php?lang=en`.