# htaccess RewriteRule string with parameters to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I need to rewrite url

```
mydomain.com/?view=article&id=288:article_name&catid=116
```

to

```
mydomain.com/
```

How to do that?

I tried

1.

```
RewriteRule ^?view=article&id=288:article_name&catid=116$ / [R=301,L]
```

No success.

2.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ?view=article&id=288:article_name&catid=116
RewriteRule .*$ /? [L,R=301]
```

When i test i get "We failed to execute your regular expression, is it valid?" on RewriteCond.

Comment: Use a `RewriteCond` to match query string

Comment: Please put in a bit of research effort, _before_ you automatically ask "how do I do that" as soon as someone mentions something new to you. [How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)

Comment: Thank you. It seems that everything should work with rewritecond.. But it doesnt.

Comment: 'When i test i get "We failed to execute your regular expression, is it valid?"' - Where are you seeing that response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ?view=article&id=288:article_name&catid=116
> RewriteRule .*$ /? [L,R=301]
> ```

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable does not itself contain the `?` prefix. However, `?` is a special meta character in the regex (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) so this is not valid.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `.*$` also matches *everything*, yet your example is the root only.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=article&id=288:article_name&catid=116$
RewriteRule ^$ /? [L,R=301]
```

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing (301s are cached persistently by the browser by default).