# Redirect all with these url paths

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Looking to redirect URLs like this with multiple numbers following the first `2`

```
/a/2/galvin-blog?jssCart=245454462464434
```

And this with multiple numbers following the first `2`

```
/s/245/restaurant-london?jssCart=269696976976
```

Also URLs like this (no numbers or letters following `4`)

```
/addons/step1.php?r=ASA&ifm=popup&day_session=4
```

To redirect all three scenarios to
mydomain.com

I tried this but not working

```
Redirect 301 "/s/245/restaurant-london?jssCart=269696976976/" "/url-path/"
```

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please revise your question (there is an "edit" button below the question). Explain why exactly you are unable to implement the rules yourself. What issues you face with that. Be more specific in your descriptions of the desired logic. Add specific examples for the redirections you want to implement.

Comment: "with multiple numbers following the 2" - There are multiple "2"s in the example URLs. Do you mean the last "2" - the value of the `jssCart` URL param? You've not stated the URLs you are wanting to redirect to (this can affect how you construct the rule).

Comment: "no numbers following `4`" - So you could have letters and other URL parameters?

Comment: Have edited the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I match query string variables with mod\_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite)