# .htaccess redirect some Opencart pages to the new domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I am having trouble setting up redirects from the old website pages to the new domain.

Opencart Version 1.5.3.1

I need to set up redirects for 5-10 pages of a similar format. For example:

```
/index.php?route=product/product&path=2_8&product_id=NNN
```

I would appreciate any assistance.

My `.htaccess` right now:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

A redirect rule of the following kind is not working:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/product&path=2_8&product_id=135 https://newdomain.com/new_page/
```

Comment: _"A redirect rule of the following kind is not working"_ - both the `RewriteRule` and the `Redirect` directive match against the URL _path_ only. If you want to rewrite a request based on query string contents, then you need to combine a RewriteRule with a RewriteCond, see [How can I match query string variables with mod_rewrite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2252238/1427878)

Comment: @CBroe thank you for your response. The issue is that it won't be possible to set up redirects using rules. I am leaning towards the necessity of specifying redirect rules directly in the Opencart template.

Comment: _"The issue is that it won't be possible to set up redirects using rules."_ - why not? Your existing .htaccess is using mod_rewrite functionality already, so the module must be available ...

Answer (score 0):

> My `.htaccess` right now

I assume you also have a `RewriteEngine On` directive at the top of the file? (Otherwise, you need it!)

> ```
> Redirect 301 /index.php?route=product/product&path=2_8&product_id=135 https://newdomain.com/new_page/
> ```

As mentioned in comments, the `Redirect` (mod_alias) directive matches against the URL-path only, so the above directive (that includes a query string) will never match.

Since you are already using mod_rewrite, you should use mod_rewrite for this redirect as well and you need to combine this with a `RewriteCond` directive in order to match the query string.

For example, your rule should be like this at the *top* of the `.htaccess` file, before your existing directives:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =route=product/product&path=2_8&product_id=135
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://newdomain.com/new_page/ [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Note that the `=` prefix on the preceding *CondPattern* makes this an exact string match, not a regex.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4) discards the original query string from the redirected request.

**UPDATE:**

> When using QSD in RewriteRule, I was getting a 500 error.

That would suggest you are on an (outdated) Apache 2.2 server. In that case you would need to remove the query string by appending an empty query string to the *substitution* string. (The *browser* then strips the trailing `?` from the request.)

For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://newdomain.com/new_page/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: When using QSD in RewriteRule, I was getting a 500 error. After some minor changes, it started working as intended. Thanks for the hint.

Working solution below

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=product/product&path=2_8&product_id=135
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ https://newdomain.com/new_page/? [L,R=301]`

Comment: @megamosk If using the QSD flag results in a 500 error then that would suggest you are on an (outdated) Apache 2.2 server. (The `QSD` flag requires Apache 2.4+) Yes, appending an empty query string would be the solution on earlier versions of Apache. I've updated my answer, although this is essentially the same as what I posted in my answer.