Redirect 301 every page that contains the same parameter
Mod_rewrite - remove question mark with parameter and redirect 301 in .htaccess.
Is it possible to remove the ?number= parameter that each of my pages contains and redirect 301 without this parameter?
Until now:
www.mysite.de/directory/second/goodproduct?number=SW11538.1

to
www.mysite.de/directory/second/goodproduct/SW11538.1

The directory names are often different and a site can also have such directories:
www.mysite.de/otherdirectory/third/greatproduct?number=SW11540.5

I want to redirect without the ?number=
I'm really overwhelmed with regular expressions

You will need to use a RewriteCond to match against the query string, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2252238/how-can-i-match-query-string-variables-with-mod-rewrite
