# redirect all wildcard subdomains to root domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay, I have done a fair amount of searching but still can't find something specific enough to handle my problem.

Right now I have a DNS record that redirects all other subdomains to my server. What I'm asking is what would make `example.mydomain.com` return `HTTP/1.1 301` and redirect to just `mydomain.com`

My apologies if this has been covered, I just couldn't find anything specific enough.

Comment: Note: ["How long do browsers cache HTTP 301"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130422/how-long-do-browsers-cache-http-301s)  and
["301 vs 302"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` to match domains other than `mydomain.com` and 301 redirect them:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the domain (any domain) is not exactly mydomain.com...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

You can also look more specifically for subdomains of `mydomain.com`. The one above would match *any* other domain.

```
# Match only subdomains of mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges not only www. - it also matches _any subdomain_ `subdomain.mydomain.com` or anything other than exactly `mydomain.com` . The top example would also redirect `mydomain.org` to `mydomain.com` while the bottom matches only subdomains and would only redirect `subdomain.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`

Comment: `RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]` produces traling slashes, e.g. `www.example.com` redirects to `example.com//`. `RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com$1 [L,R=301,QSA]` seems to be correct.

Comment: @akarienta It would depend on the context. If you use it in .htaccess or `<Directory>` (if I recall), then the `(.*)` will not capture a leading `/`. But if you use it in a `<VirtualHost>` at the server level, it will include a leading `/`. There's a note about this in the docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: @Michael Berkowski ah I see. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: it's not working.I am using GoDaddy server.please help

Answer (score 2):

In my case I need rule like `foo.bar.com` > `bar.com/page/foo` and I found in apache documentation this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.bar\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.bar.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://bar.com/page/%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/migrate-domains/) Covers .htacces and ModRewrite to redirect any request made to any domin other than the primary one redirect to the primary domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [evan's blog](http://blog.evan.pro/how-to-set-up-dynamic-virtual-hosts-for-web-development), you might configure your ServerAlias with wildcard "*" if you make apache as your server side.  Every visit to the subdomain will be redirected or routed to the root domain in this case.

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
VirtualDocumentRoot "/path/to/your/workspace/%1/public"
ServerName vhosts.dev
ServerAlias *.dev
UseCanonicalName Off
<Directory "/path/to/your/workspace/*">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```