# How to match dynamic sub-domain alias to sub-folder on apache server

Tags: php, linux, apache, dns, subdomain

I am currently developing a SaaS web based project using PHP which requires users to have unique sub-domains to use the application.

I am done configuring the server with wildcards: Eg. `user.example.com` ==> `*.example.com`. The application creates a subfolder for the user under `/var/www/html/` with the name of the user Eg. `user.example.com` would be in `/var/www/html/user/`.

I am stuck on getting the user's link without the base folder such as `user.example.com` to point to `/var/www/html/user/` without having to include `http://user.example.com/user`.

I have tried virtual host and aliases but it seems like I have to manually assign the variable which is not applicable for the project.

I just need the subdomains to point to their respective subfolders.

My apache config file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@xxxxxxx.tdl
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/
        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
        ErrorDocument 404 /error_404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388618/redirect-all-wildcard-subdomains-to-root-domain
I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: This question describes how to redirect wildcard subdomains to root domain. I am interested with redirecting subdomains to their respective  root folders. Thanks though.

Comment: try using .htaccess

Comment: Please share your current Apache configuration for your virtual host.

Answer (score 2):

Finally after researching I got a solution. I realised that I had not activate the alias module and so I activated as follows:

```
    sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
```

I also noted that serving each sub-domain to its respective sub-folder required a dynamic config script to auto-pick the VirtualDocumentRoot through Directory Name Interpolation as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@vspace.ke
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/
        <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also noted that you have to declare all sub-domains and non sub domain in the host configurations:
**I.E**
Alias for www

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.vspace.ke
    ServerAlias www
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Alias for no sub-domain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vspace.ke
    ServerAlias
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And * (wild card) sub-domain

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin admin@vspace.ke
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1/
        <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thank you so much for contributing.