# IIS: SSL Site not respond to all browsers/devices by https

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, https, ssl-certificate

I've installed a Geotrust certificate for my site, which run over IIS7. The certificate is correctly installed, but I am getting an unexpected result. When I make a request to a http://example.com, it Works well on every browser/device, but when I make a request to https://example.com, it only responds in some browsers/devices, examples:
- On the same PC respond well only in Firefox, but not in IE or Chrome.
- On others PCs not respond to any browsers.
- The strangest, in my Smartphone, not respond through wifi, but when I am connected over 3G the site respond properly to https.
- I also test in a labtop, via wifi the site dont respond, but if I share the 3g connection from the Smartphone to the labtop, the web Works properly.

**EDIT**: the result of the openssl command:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
CONNECTED(000001C4)
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=ES/ST=Malaga/L=Malaga/O=domain/CN=www.domain.net/OU=domain
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIExjCCA66gAwIBAgIQeee0uwSySeNXOkI+BUoMMzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBE
MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEWMBQGA1UEChMNR2VvVHJ1c3QgSW5jLjEdMBsGA1UEAxMU
...
doLsKI2R6RQA/7IcuTpKkvLF5wYKvmocPxYVg9FOoFvKV0wjWo6qlwsANPAVov+7
zFzZreROa7lBj8UH0IyYjLmBrbe1yMr/Cmg=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=ES/ST=Malaga/L=Malaga/O=domain/CN=www.domain.net/OU=domain
issuer=/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3405 bytes and written 645 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: D80B0000C341A313FBA6527E6576D1D71ACA71E680528EE880649C8166AA7C1B

    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: F1D5AB2E543959B3D100CC16365884DEFF06E56E3C57839A64088744FFCAEDCE
24B744836326E46828537C64884081B0
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1407168950
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
```

After some searching and testing some ideas I have not done anything and I'm going crazy. Any idea?

Comment: Client side certificates are a mess in browsers. For testing, you should disable them. See [Specify Whether to Use Client Certificates (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

> ... but when I make a request to https://example.com, it only responds in some browsers/devices...

OK, the certificate chain looks OK. I grabbed your server's name out of the cert you posted for the tests below. You can run your certificate through `openssl x509` and see the `CN` and `SAN`:

```
$ openssl x509 -in server-cert.pem -inform PEM -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            79:e7:b4:bb:04:b2:49:e3:57:3a:42:3e:05:4a:0c:33
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=GeoTrust Inc., CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 11 00:00:00 2014 GMT
            Not After : Jun 11 23:59:59 2015 GMT
        Subject: C=ES, ST=Malaga, L=Malaga, O=Example, CN=www.example.com, OU=Example, LLC
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:a2:f6:fd:b0:30:10:91:55:3f:ec:ce:fa:d8:9e:
                    84:cd:60:c4:dd:a8:f0:42:37:66:a9:98:80:35:d8:
                    ...
                    13:db:e9:98:c5:1a:ac:31:50:70:e1:6e:8d:1f:2a:
                    7d:b5
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.example.com, DNS:example.com
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://gb.symcb.com/gb.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.16.840.1.113733.1.7.54
                  CPS: https://d.symcb.com/cps
                  User Notice:
                    Explicit Text: https://d.symcb.com/rpa

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:11:4A:D0:73:39:D5:5B:69:08:5C:BA:3D:BF:64:9A:A8:8B:1C:55:BC

            Authority Information Access: 
                OCSP - URI:http://gb.symcd.com
                CA Issuers - URI:http://gb.symcb.com/gb.crt

    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         52:60:0e:f3:c7:fb:16:49:cf:4f:7c:91:d9:c9:b9:d5:92:62:
         75:c9:05:f1:b7:cf:ea:30:53:44:5d:a7:1e:c7:eb:fd:a9:ab:
         ...
         e4:4e:6b:b9:41:8f:c5:07:d0:8c:98:8c:b9:81:ad:b7:b5:c8:
         ca:ff:0a:68
```

You have *both* `example.com` and `www.example.com`. That is OK.

One small nitpick. Placing a DNS name in the Common Name (CN) is deprecated by both the IETF and CA/Browser forums. DNS names *should* be placed in the Subject Alternate Name (SAN). Put a friendly name in the CN because its usually displayed to the user.

The issue should *not* produce the problem you are experiencing. In fact, I use Startcom certificates for my web and mail server and have never had an issue.

---

Next, OpenSSL's *"Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)"* complaint is because you are *not* using `CAfile` option with `<Equifax Secure Certificate Authority>.pem`. If interested, you can download it from [GeoTrust Root Certificates](http://www.geotrust.com/resources/root-certificates/). I'll use it below to ensure a *"Verify return code: 0 (ok)"*.

Now, check this out (SSLv3):

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 \
    -ssl3 -ign_eof -CAfile Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem 

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=3 C = US, O = Equifax, OU = Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
verify return:1
depth=2 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust Global CA
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = GeoTrust Inc., CN = GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
verify return:1
depth=0 C = ES, ST = Malaga, L = Malaga, O = Example, LLC, CN = www.example.com, OU = Example, LLC
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=ES/ST=Malaga/L=Malaga/O=Example, LLC/CN=www.example.com/OU=Example, LLC
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
 1 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust SSL CA - G2
   i:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
 2 s:/C=US/O=GeoTrust Inc./CN=GeoTrust Global CA
   i:/C=US/O=Equifax/OU=Equifax Secure Certificate Authority
---
...
    Start Time: 1407401571
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 07 Aug 2014 08:52:28 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 334

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
read:errno=0
```

And (TLS 1.0 with SNI):

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n" | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 \
    -tls1 -servername example.com -ign_eof -CAfile Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem 

CONNECTED(00000003)
...
    Start Time: 1407401898
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 07 Aug 2014 08:57:55 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 334

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
read:errno=0
```

It does not appear to be Server Name Indication (SNI) related. I'm not sure SNI being honored at this point. Is this IIS 7.5 or below? [IIS 8 provides SNI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/09/04/server-name-indication-sni-in-iis-8-windows-server-2012.aspx), and that might help the issue since the request will be routed immediately to the correct virtual domain in IIS.

Next, add a host header:

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost:example.com\n" | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 \
    -ssl3 -ign_eof -CAfile Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem 

CONNECTED(00000003)
...
    Start Time: 1407402117
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
read R BLOCK
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /Login/Login
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=310xiuzver13lqoau0il0tsu; path=/; HttpOnly
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 07 Aug 2014 09:01:34 GMT
```

The 302 redirect looks wrong. Shouldn't that be a 301? See [HTTP redirect: 301 (permanent) vs. 302 (temporary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary). Also check out [How can I make Chrome stop caching redirects?](https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects) and the "won't fix" bug.

---

For completeness, here's the result following the redirect to `/Login/Login`:

```
$ echo -e "GET /Login/Login HTTP/1.1\nHost:example.com\n" | openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 \
    -ssl3 -ign_eof -CAfile Equifax_Secure_Certificate_Authority.pem 

CONNECTED(00000003)    
...
    Start Time: 1407403671
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)

read R BLOCK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 07 Aug 2014 09:27:29 GMT
Content-Length: 1547

<html>
<body>
<form action="/Login/Login" method="post">        <div style="height: 140px">
        </div>   
        <table style="width: 400px; border: 1px solid #058fbe;" cellpadding="5" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" style="background-color: #058fbe">
                    <span style="color: #FFF; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                     font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt">TERRANET. ZONA ADMINISTRACIÓN</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="150px">
                    <img src="/Content/img/login.png" width="150px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span style="color: #058fbe; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                     font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt">usuario</span><br />
                    <input type="text" style="border: 1px solid #058fbe; width: 190px" name="usuario" /><br />
                    <span style="color: #058fbe; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                     font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt">contraseña</span><br />
                    <input type="password" style="border: 1px solid #058fbe; width: 190px" name="pass" /><br />
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="entrar" style="background-color: #058fbe; 
                     width: 80px; color: white; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
                     font-weight: bold; font-size: 10pt; border: none" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT** (August 7, 2014): I see your changes of `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently`.

I performed some browsers tests today. I used:

- Chrome (Mac Book)
- Firefox (Mac Book)
- Safari (Mac Book).
- Mobile Browser (Android)
- Mobile Chrome (iPhone)
- Mobile Safari (iPhone)
- Explorer (Surface Pro)

Most worked as expected.

Explorer on the Surface Pro tablet hung.

Android's browser (`com.android.browser`) prompted for a client cert (that's why I am being prompted to set a PIN):

[image]

Safari desktop prompted for a client cert:

[image]

Do you need client certificates? If so, that's probably the issue. Client side certificates are a mess in browsers.

If you don't need them, then disable them in IIS. See [Specify Whether to Use Client Certificates (IIS 7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Comment: I have changed the 302 for 301 permanent redirection. But I do not quite understand how to fix the problem. You could connect using the Secure Certificate <Equifax Authority> certificate. pem from your computer. Do I have to install this certificate on the server to fix the problem? How have you seen the server is IIS7.5, and I can not upgrade to IIS8.

Comment: @Carlos: *"Do I have to install this certificate on the server to fix the problem?"* - no, SSL/TLS on the site is fine. The issue is elsewhere. I just performed some browser tests. Chrome and Firefox were OK since changing the redirect. Safari is prompting me for a client certificate. Do you have client certs enabled on IIS?

Comment: After change 302 for 301 and change use client certificate from accept to ignore I havent apreciate any change. The site only respond when I try in a Surface pro using Firefox, and in the Smartphone (Windows phone) ONLY when using 3G connection. Beside when I share connection from the Smartphone (3G) to any labtop it always Works fine. This makes me think the problem is related to network more with the browser, can it be?

Answer (score 2):

This may be because of IP binding as to get it worked properly your HTTPS and HTTP both should bind to same IP address in IIS.

Have you tried restarting your IIS? it may resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi Jack, I restarted the IIS, even I restarted the server without any result.

Comment: did u bind port 443 in the domain name?