# Remap domain.io to show as domain.com in address bar

Tags: apache, ubuntu, url-rewriting, dns

I have domain.io and domain.com BOTH pointing to the SAME server. How do I set this up so that domain.io never shows up in the address bar, and it's always domain.com?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Apache's [mod_alias Redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive for this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.io
    ServerAlias www.domain.io
    Redirect permanent / http://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

In your case, `permanent` (301) redirect sounds appropriate but you may want to look at [HTTP redirect: 301 (permanent) vs. 302 (temporary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary)

Also, it's really unimportant where the domains are hosted in this case; they do not need to be on the same server. In fact, many DNS and web host providers actually provide this functionality as a service, and will host the equivalent of above configuration for you (though not necessarily with Apache; nginx is probably more likely for this purpose these days).