# nginx 301 permanent redirect Urls to page/Folder

Tags: redirect, nginx, http-status-code-301

i need to redirect few URLs. 301 permanent

http://example.com/downloads/example.exe to http://example.com/emaple-page/

i need to do this for 3 URLS , i'm going to do this on .conf file

```
 server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://example.com/downloads/example.exe;

    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/emaple-page/$1 permanent;
}
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://example.com/downloads/example2.exe;

    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/emaple-page/$1 permanent;
}
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://example.com/downloads/example3.exe;

    rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/emaple-page/$1 permanent;
}
```

i want to know is this correct ? what is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have only 1 `server` section for each domain. You can put the original URL directly in the `rewrite` clause.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  index index.html index.php
  rewrite ^/downloads/example\.exe  http://example.com/emaple-page/  permanent;
  rewrite ^/downloads/example2\.exe http://example.com/emaple-page2/ permanent;
  rewrite ^/downloads/example3\.exe http://example.com/emaple-page3/ permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i will try this one ! i think its OK with SEO ?

Comment: For SEO question read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18556097/1129642 (basically google will rewrite the old URL to new one in its database)

Comment: Thanks , your first solution is up and running :)

Comment: hey , its just working for the above URLs. Site is not loading ( default nginx index page)

Comment: For that to work you need to add the `index` directive (see edited answer). I didn't include it first as it was not part of your original config...

Comment: what will happen to other URLs/pages/folders ?   i just need to redirect those 3 URLS. All the other stuff must work as before