# trapping an exception using IExceptionFilter and redirecting permanently binds the path to error page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, exception, unhandled-exception

I am trying to redirect unhandled exceptions to an error page by first generating a crash code and then redirecting the user to the error page. The problem is that after the first time it happens, the original url/action is permanently mapped to the error page url and doesn't even enter the OnException method anymore. Even after I fix the cause of the original exception, the url/action is still mapped to just redirect to the error page. Not sure where this is happening or how to fix it.  Below is the code:

```
public class UnhandledExceptionFilter : IExceptionFilter
{
       protected static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var ex = filterContext.Exception;

            if (ex != null)
            {
                string user = "";
                try
                {
                    user = Managers.UserManager.FindByUsername(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, true).FullName;
                }
                catch
                {
                }
                var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString();
                var urlRef = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
                var randStr = StringExtensions.GenerateRandomAlphaNumerics(new System.Random(), 4);
                Logger.Error(ex, "crashCode={0} - user={1} - url={2} - urlRef={3}", randStr, user, url, urlRef);
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/misc/whoops?crash_code=" + randStr, true);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be solved by not passing true to the second parameter of RedirectResult.  Pass false instead:

`filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("/misc/whoops?crash_code=" + randStr, false);`

Passing true as the second parameter indicates the redirect is permanent.  Which is, based on your question, exactly want you do not want.

See: [MSDN RedirectResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.redirectresult(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.RedirectResult.) and
     [301 vs 302 redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary)