# What's the difference between a permanent and non-permanent redirect in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I don't know what part is "permanent" or not. Is this related to SEO? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP redirect: 301 (permanent) vs. 302 (temporary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393280/http-redirect-301-permanent-vs-302-temporary)

Answer (score 2):

The `permanent` flag as `true` would be a 301 permanent redirect whereas the `false` option would be a 302 temporary redirect.

Good canonical answer on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1393298/241153